# Raise "shadows" on monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, high-sierra

I want darker colors to be brighter on my MacBook Pro 2015 (retina display).

Every frame displayed should be as if it's gone through photoshop and the "shadows" slider has been increased.

How can I do this?

I already tried creating a new color profile in display preferences but couldn't seem to get the effect I want, maybe someone knows how I need to set those values etc. to achieve this.

Comment: Normally I'd say "you need a colorimeter..." however just this week I find myself with the same need, for a TV that's too contrasty when used as a monitor. Colour profiling it is not working well enough, so ideally I'd like some app/utility that can adjust the curves manually, just like you would in photoshop.

Comment: BTW, you know if you hold Opt whilst clicking the Calibrate button in Display/Color, you get the advanced setup, which is a bit better but still not good enough, imo.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah that's what I did, but it "distorts" other colors and bleaches mids and highs too, I tried for about 4 hours lmfao

Comment: tbh, I've never struggled before except with this TV. All the actual computer monitors in the house were done with the i1Display Profiler... to perfection. This damn, telly... not playing ball. I think I'm on about my 30th calibration run right now :(

Comment: I've just discovered this software - [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net/) which I'm running across my regular monitors right now. Cool thing about it is it will apparently use just about any colorimeter out there. I've got the i1 but it will even apparently work with a Pantone Huey [which long ago stopped being supported on Mac] Bet you could pick one of those up for a tenner on eBay. Just about to run it on the TV, I'll let you know how it goes...

Comment: ***Yes !!*** DisplayCAL has got the TV closest yet. Desktop looks pretty close, VLC movies look great.